# Graphviz: reducing margin on skewed polygon node

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to use a skewed polygon (aka parallelogram) on Graphviz, the problem is there is too much space between parallelogram border and it's text.

```
digraph G {
    poly1[margin=0, width=0, height=0, shape=polygon, label="This is a polygon\nwithout skew"]
    poly2[margin=0, width=0, height=0, shape=polygon, label="This is a polygon\nwith skew", skew=0.3]
}
```

This is the result of previous code:

[image: Graphviz polygon w/ and w/o skew]

As you can see, as soon I set a skew value (ìn this case `skew=0.3`) the polygon's interior margin increases a lot. Setting `margin=0`, `width=0` and `height=0` does not solve the issue.

Is there a way to remove the polygon's interior margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way, but it ain't pretty:

```
digraph G {
    poly1[margin=0, width=0, height=0, shape=polygon, label="This is a polygon\nwithout skew"]
    poly2[margin=0, width=1.8, height=0.46, shape=polygon, fixedsize=true, label="This is a polygon\nwith skew", skew=0.3]
}
```

Adding `fixedsize=true` and specifying the node's width and height (by trial and error) yields this:

[image: skewed result :)]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in graphviz; if there is no way to make it automatically scale with the size of a label while maintaining a margin of zero.